# Why does the line tool not work in 2d?

Tags: texturing

Ok I am very new to blender and how it works so if I could get a response that would be great. But whenever I use the line tool and I put the line down in the drawing area and I left click it just disappears I tried to snap it but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the drawn line you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.